# Highchart will not populate php JSON call

Tags: php, json, highcharts

I'm having problem populating my highchart with JSON data.  When I execute the script in a webpage, the data will populate the specific area where the chart needs but when I try and use highcharts nothing comes up.

When I get rid of my php and plug in a static number the chart will create itself.

To sum it up, Highcharts won't work when I run my php script (but the data is being generated) and when I plug in static numbers and delete my php script the chart runs.

```
  $response = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID.'/insights  /page_views?access_token='.FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN);
  $page = json_decode($response);



 if ($page && $page->data) {

$test = $page->data[0]->values[2]->end_time; $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($test));  
$gender = $page->data[0]->values[2]->value; 

$test2 = $page->data[0]->values[1]->end_time;  $newDate1 = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($test2)); 
$gender1 = $page->data[0]->values[1]->value; 

$test3 = $page->data[0]->values[0]->end_time;  $newDate2 = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($test3)); 
$gender2 = $page->data[0]->values[0]->value; 


}

 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 ?>
 {
 chart: {
  renderTo: 'container',
  height: 220,
  type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
  text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
  categories: ['apples'],
  lineWidth: 0,
  tickWidth: 0,
   },
   yAxis: {
   min: 0,
   title: {
   text: ''
   },
  stackLabels: {
   enabled: true,
   style: {
   fontWeight: 'bold',

   }
   }
   },
   legend: {
   align: 'left',
   x: 0,
   verticalAlign: 'left',
   y: 15,
   floating: true,
   backgroundColor: 'white',
   borderColor: '#CCC',
   borderWidth: 1,
   shadow: false
    },
   tooltip: {
   formatter: function () {
   return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
   'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
   }
   },
   plotOptions: {
   column: {
   stacking: 'normal',
    dataLabels: {
   enabled: true,
   color: 'white'
   }
   }
   },
        series: [{
            name: '<?php echo $newDate; ?> ',
            data: [<?php echo $gender; ?>]
        }, {
            name: '<?php echo $newDate1; ?>',
            data: [<?php echo $gender1; ?>]
        }, {
            name: '<?php echo $newDate2;  ?>',
            data: [<?php echo $gender2;  ?>]
        }]

      });
     });

     });
```

Here's the output that I get.

```
{
chart: {
renderTo: 'container',
height: 220,
type: 'column'
},
 title: {
 text: ''
 },
 xAxis: {
 categories: ['apples'],
 lineWidth: 0,
 tickWidth: 0,
 },
 yAxis: {
 min: 0,
 title: {
 text: ''
 },
 stackLabels: {
 enabled: true,
 style: {
 fontWeight: 'bold',

}
}
},
legend: {
align: 'left',
x: 0,
verticalAlign: 'left',
y: 15,
floating: true,
backgroundColor: 'white',
borderColor: '#CCC',
borderWidth: 1,
shadow: false
},
tooltip: {
formatter: function () {
return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
}
},
plotOptions: {
column: {
stacking: 'normal',
dataLabels: {
enabled: true,
color: 'white'
}
}
},
        series: [{
            name: '19-01-2013 ',
            data: [57]
        }, {
            name: '18-01-2013',
            data: [21]
        }, {
            name: '17-01-2013',
            data: [34]
        }]

        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Is ``file_get_contents`` working properly? Looks like you have a space in the Facebook URL

Comment: Yup, I can parse the json data and have it output in real time, It's only when I apply the highchart js that everything goes blank.  But if I get rid of the php and just plug numbers in the data slot, the js works.  I have other widgets like this but this one is seeming to give me trouble.  Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors?  What do $gender, $gender1 and $gender2 equal?

Comment: I just added what the output is for the series.  That's what generated with my php but it won't work.  If I take out the php and just add the 'name' and 'data' in manually it works just fine.  I've tried json_encode thinking I have to revert it back but that didn't work and the thing is no errors pop up.  It has to be something with my php but I can't seem to find what would be causing it.

Comment: The problem is probably that you are trying to return javascript functions in your JSON. That is not valid JSON and most libraries will not convert your string to a Javascript object. Try removing your javascript code from the JSON produced by PHP. Please post the JS code as well. Also, do you get any error messages in the browsers javascript console?

Comment: Why don't you just use the PHP wrapper for HighCharts (HighRoller)? It does the same thing your trying to do.

Comment: I'm using the function for Geckoboard.  It's a dashboard program that will configure the chart without adding the highchart js.  I have a customer rep looking into this and will update when I get an answer.  Thanks to all for taking a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working.  I basically went step by step adding code to see where it breaks and... it worked.  NO idea what happen but here's the code:

```
<?php 

require_once 'config.php';

$response = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID.'/insights    /page_views?access_token='.FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN);
$page = json_decode($response);

if ($page && $page->data) {

$test = $page->data[0]->values[2]->end_time; $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($test));  $newDate;
$gender = $page->data[0]->values[2]->value;  $gender;

$test2 = $page->data[0]->values[1]->end_time;  $newDate1 = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($test2)); $newDate1;
$gender1 = $page->data[0]->values[1]->value;  $gender1;

$test3 = $page->data[0]->values[0]->end_time;  $newDate2 = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($test3));  $newDate2;
$gender2 = $page->data[0]->values[0]->value;  $gender2;


}
header('Content-Type: application/json');

?>
 {
chart: {
renderTo: 'container',
height: 220,
type: 'column'
},
title: {
text: ''
},
xAxis: {
categories: ['Page Views'],
lineWidth: 0,
tickWidth: 0,
},
yAxis: {
min: 0,
title: {
text: ''
},
stackLabels: {
enabled: true,
style: {
fontWeight: 'bold',

}
}
},
legend: {
align: 'left',
x: 0,
verticalAlign: 'left',
y: 0,
floating: true,
backgroundColor: 'black',
borderColor: '#CCC',
borderWidth: 1,
shadow: false
},
tooltip: {
formatter: function () {
return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
}
},
plotOptions: {
column: {
stacking: 'normal',
dataLabels: {
enabled: true,
color: 'white'
}
}
},
series: [{
name: '<?php echo $newDate; ?> ',
data: [<?php echo  $gender; ?>]
}, {
name: '<?php echo $newDate1; ?>',
data: [<?php echo $gender1; ?>]
}, {
name: '<?php echo $newDate2;  ?>',
data: [<?php echo  $gender2;  ?>]
}]
}
```